# Why does the order of my divs change when I use display: inline-block;?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I created a 3 column layout for big screens (min 1200px ). I'm trying to align the columns using display: inline-block.

The problem is that the order of the columns changes (to secondary - tertiary -
primary) even though in the HTML the order is different (secondary - primary - tertiary). What seems to be the problem?

You can find the complete code example here: https://codepen.io/Cilvako/pen/brqeVN

```
 <div class="container clearfix">
        <div class="secondary col">
            <h2>Welcome!</h2>
            <p>...</p>
        </div>

        <div class="primary col">
            <h2>Great food</h2>
            <p>...</p>
        </div>

        <div class="tertiary col">
            <h2>How to get here</h2>
            <p>...</p>
            <p>...</p>
            <p>...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
.primary {
   width: 40%;
  }

.secondary,
.tertiary {
  width: 30%;
  }

.col {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem solved when I add `float: left;` to the `primary` class under `@media (min-width: 1200px)`

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VzpjMR

Comment: Yes, this worked. It makes sense,  it has overwritten the style I applied for the previous media query. Thx.

Comment: @CasiaHospi It will be nice if you mark this answer as the correct one

Answer (score 2):

Because you're also `float`ing those elements left and right. Remove the floats, then remove the white space between the elements so the `30%, 40%, 30%` elements will all be on the same row and be `100%` total.

```css
/* ================================= 
  Base Element Styles
==================================== */

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.6;
 color: #3a3a3a;
}

p {
 font-size: .95em;
 margin-bottom: 1.8em;
}

h2,
h3,
a {
 color: #093a58;
}

h2,
h3 {
 margin-top: 0;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

img {
 max-width: 100%;
}

/* ================================= 
  Base Layout Styles
==================================== */

/* ---- Navigation ---- */

.name {
 font-size: 1.25em;
}

.name a,
.main-nav a {
 text-align: center;
}

.main-nav a {
 font-size: .95em;
 color: #3acec2;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-nav a:hover {
 color: #093a58;
}

.main-nav li {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.main-header,
.banner,
.main-footer {
  text-align: center; 
  
}

/* ---- Layout Containers ---- */

.banner {
 color: #fff;
 background: #3acec2;
  padding: 40px;
}

.main-footer {
 background: #d9e4ea;
 padding: 2em 0;
 margin-top: 30px;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

/* ---- Page Elements ---- */

.logo {
 width: 190px;
}

.headline {
   margin-bottom: -.2rem;
}

/* ================================= 
  Media Queries
==================================== */

@media (min-width: 769px) {

/* ---- Header ---- */

.name {
  float: left;
  margin: 1.5rem 0 0 1.7rem;
}

.main-nav {
  float: right;
}

.main-nav li {
  margin-top: 1.3rem;
  padding: .5rem 1.7rem;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* ---- Page content ---- */

.primary {
  width: 47.5%;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  
}

.secondary {
  width: 45%;
 
}

.tertiary {
  clear: both;
}

 /* ---- Float clearfix ---- */

 .clearfix::after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
 }

}


@media (min-width: 1200px) {


/* ---- Page content ---- */

.container {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1150px;
 
}


.primary {
   width: 40%;
  
}

.secondary,
.tertiary {
  width: 30%;
  
}

.col {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
}


 /* ---- Float clearfix ---- */

 .clearfix::after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
 }

}
```

```html
<header class="main-header clearfix">
  <h1 class="name"><a href="#">Best City Guide</a></h1>
  <ul class="main-nav">
   <li><a href="#">ice cream</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">donuts</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">tea</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">coffee</a></li>
  </ul>
 </header><!--/.main-header-->   

  
 <div class="banner">
  <h1 class="headline">The Best City</h1>
  <span class="tagline">The best drinks and eats in the best city ever.</span>
 </div><!--/.banner-->
 
  
  <div class="container clearfix">
 <div class="secondary col">
  <h2>Welcome!</h2>
  <p>Everything in this city is worth waiting in line for.</p>
  <p>Cupcake ipsum dolor sit. Amet chocolate cake gummies jelly beans candy bonbon brownie candy. Gingerbread powder muffin. Icing cotton candy. Croissant icing pie ice cream brownie I love cheesecake cookie. Pastry chocolate pastry jelly croissant.</p>
  <p>Cake sesame snaps sweet tart candy canes tiramisu I love oat cake chocolate bar. Jelly beans pastry brownie sugar plum pastry bear claw tiramisu tootsie roll. Tootsie roll wafer I love chocolate donuts.</p>
 </div><div class="primary col">
  <h2>Great food</h2>
  <p>Croissant macaroon pie brownie. Cookie marshmallow liquorice gingerbread caramels toffee I love chocolate. Wafer lollipop dessert. Bonbon jelly beans pudding dessert sugar plum. Marzipan toffee drag&#233;e chocolate bar candy toffee pudding I love. Gummi bears pie gingerbread lollipop.</p>
 </div><div class="tertiary col">
  <h2>How to get here</h2>
  <p><strong>Plane: </strong>Tiramisu caramels gummies chupa chups lollipop muffin. Jujubes chocolate caramels cheesecake brownie lollipop drag&#233;e cheesecake.</p>
  <p><strong>Train: </strong>Pie apple pie pudding I love wafer toffee liquorice sesame snaps lemon drops. Lollipop gummi bears dessert muffin I love fruitcake toffee pie.</p>
  <p><strong>Car: </strong>Jelly cotton candy bonbon jelly-o jelly-o I love. I love sugar plum chocolate cake pie I love pastry liquorice.</p>
 </div><!--/.tertiary--> 
    </div>

 <footer class="main-footer">
  <span>&copy;2017 Residents of The Best City Ever.</span>
 </footer>
```

Comment: In your example, the layout doesn't behave as expected for min-width: 769px, I just see one column from mobile layout to wide screens layout. But now I do understand what happens... I have 2 conflicting media queries. Thank you.